# css min-height ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

My content box's last part doesn't show up in ie8, in ffox and chrome works fine.

```
    .container
{
    width: 1000px;
    min-height:1200px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:1200px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

If i use overflow:hidden; no change..
whats wrong?

Comment: Are you familiar with firebug at all? Can you check to make sure its not inheriting something? The IE hack looks correct to me.

Comment: if I incrase the menu (left_side) height, it's works. But I dont understand, I have a container div, which contains the header, and menu(float:left), and content(float:left), but if the menu is sorter then content, the content doesnt growing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are floating elements within a container, you might want to consider adding `overflow:hidden` to the parent container. This will clear the floats within the container. It's quite hard to predict what the problem is without seeing a live version.

I would still recommend putting your html and css up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for everyone to see and have a play with.

Comment: However, overflow:hidden will not work if the parent element does not have a fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

You've got `height` in there twice:

```
min-height: 1200px;
height: auto !important;
height: 1200px;
```

Comment: He's using the IE min height hack.

Comment: Ahh I've never seen that particular hack before.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use clear div's. It's bad practice and can always be done using pure css (overflow:hidden).

Look at the double height property which is probably the problem.

Comment: @user617573, After your comment I decided to take a look into the subject and came across an article '8 Common CSS mistakes ...' (number 7): http://www.pxleyes.com/blog/2010/03/8-common-css-mistakes-and-how-to-fix-them/ And, you are right - thanks for enlightening me =)

Comment: Didn't know about the overflow:hidden myself, will try this out. +1 for the heads up